# Trigger release stage from completing PR

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Currently I have a release pipeline like so:

The artifact has a `pull request trigger` to the `master` branch. So each time there's a PR to master this release is triggered.

[image]

On my master branch I have a `status policy` for `VSTS-RM/Pokedex Release` which is the name for the release pipeline. In my PR I can see the policy working.

So when I create a new PR the build pipeline is triggered to create a new build of that branch. If the build is successful the `development` stage in the `Pokedex Release` pipeline is triggered. So this all works fine.

When I complete the PR the development branch is merged into master. But there's nothing happening in the `production` stage of the `Pokedex Release` pipeline.

[image]

This is the `Pre-deployment conditions` configuration from the `Production` stage:

[image]

So without any triggers it's not too weird that nothing is happening.

So how do I trigger the `production` stage in the current `Pokedex release` pipeline from completing a PR?

Answer (score 0):

`Pull  request deployment` is meant for that specifically:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops

You also need to enable pull request trigger on the trigger screen

Comment: I can't find anything about triggering a release stage from completing a PR. It looks like this is only how to set up a release from a PR. That's what I already have.I want to trigger a release stage from completing the PR. I've set up the `production` stage with a PR trigger but:

`Artifact conditions not met Deployment will not start automatically as the following 
artifact condition(s) are not met _Pokedex master from refs/pull/87/merge cannot be deployed as the stage trigger condition(s) are set to Include master`

Comment: you want to trigger release after pr was merged?

Comment: Yes. If you see my question I have 2 stages in my release. The first stage is a "feature release". This will create a app-service based on the branch name for the PO to review what ever is being build. This stage is also added to the branch policy of master. So a PR cannot be completed unless this stage is released successfully. 

I also have a `production` stage in my release pipeline. When the PR is completed a new build will be triggered. I want to deploy the artifact of that build in my `production` stage.

Comment: so whats the problem, just create a trigger that the release will start when that build finishes